# How to include raspicam class into C++/ Geany

Tags: c++, camera, shared-libraries, raspberry-pi3

I'm having trouble linking my libraries on C++ so I can use my pi camera. I'm trying to follow this guys instructions

http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40

But then it says after uncompressing the file that I need to compile it.. I've tried putting it into terminal, tried compiling it straight from Geany... I don't understand what it means and everywhere on the internet seems to think this is knowledge everyone has?

I'm using a raspberry pi 3 with Raspibian installed. My camera module is the raspberry pi camera v2.

Answer (score 0):

So as I read the description.
Download the file as described in the [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspicam/files/?). Choose the file which is the newest Version.
Then do as follow:

```
cd <Directory where you downloaded the file>  //probably cd  ~/Downloads
tar xvzf raspicamxx.tgz //extract file replace xx with version number
cd raspicamxx //seitch to newly created directory
mkdir build // make new directory calle build
cd build // switch into build 
cmake .. // compile it
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

If you get errors post them here.